# List of tcolorbox in tufte-book

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, tufte

Normally `\tcblistof` works fine, but not with the `tufte-book` class and I cannot figure out why. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
% \documentclass{book} % this works
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=thm]{theo}{Theorem}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \tcblistof[\chapter*]{thm}{List of Theorems}
    \chapter{Chapter No1}
    \begin{theo}{Theorem No1}{}
        lipsum
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Using the `book` class works as expected. What do I have to change for `tufte-book`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has already found a solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554289/79060). Here I'd like to provide some general discussions.

`tufte-book` class contains lines

```
% Only show the chapter titles in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

and since `tcolorbox` defines `\l@tcolorbox` as level 1 by

```
\newcommand*\l@tcolorbox{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

therefore `\tcblistof[\chapter*]{thm}{List of Theorems}` produces nothing but a list title.

Locally using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` is a workaround, but the produced list entries may not share the same style with list of figures and tables. Currently entries in these two list are defined as

```
\newcommand{\@tufte@lof@line}[2]{%
  % #1 is the figure/table number and its caption text
  % #2 is the page number on which the figure/table appears
  \leftskip 0.0em
  \rightskip 0em
  \parfillskip 0em plus 1fil
  \parindent 0.0em
  \@afterindenttrue
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \leavevmode
  \@tempdima 2.0em
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
  \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
  {#1}\nobreak\qquad\nobreak#2%
  \par%
}

\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@tufte@lof@line}
\let\l@table\l@figure
```

Hence OP's answer `\let\l@tcolorbox\l@figure` *is* a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if I add

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@tcolorbox\l@figure
\makeatother
```